# Show that for each $a\in [0, \infty)$, the subspace $[a, \infty)$ is also compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

i) Show that the intervals $(a, \infty)$, $a \in (0, \infty)$ together with $\emptyset$ and $[0, \infty)$ form a topology on $[0, \infty)$.

ii) Show that in this topology $[0, \infty)$ is compact. Show that for each $a \in [0, \infty)$, the subspace $[a, \infty)$ is also compact.

iii) Notice that intersection $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty [k,\infty)= \emptyset$,why doesn’t this contradict the statement that “the intersection of a decreasing sequence of nonempty compact sets is nonempty.”

this is not homework, it is from a book with no solutions.

i is easy from definition and checking union and intersection.

Comment: What topology are you working with? If you are working in the Euclidean metric space, then $[0, \infty)$ is not compact since it is not bounded.

Comment: He is defining the topology.

Comment: Please use actual words, not "defn, soln" and so on.

Comment: Your topology is known as the right order topology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Left_and_right_order_topologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i) is straightforward.

For ii), note that if $\cal O$ is an open cover of $[a,\infty)$, then at least one element of $\cal O$ must contain the point $a$. If $a=0$, then the only set satisfying this is  $[0,\infty)$, and if $a>0$, then there must exists a set of the form $[b,\infty) \in {\cal O}$ where $b < a$ (otherwise $\cup_{U \in {\cal O}} U = (a, \infty)$). Hence there exists a finite cover.

For iii), the statement should be in terms of closed, not compact sets. In this particular topology, the only non-empty compact sets that is closed is $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Just to add a little bit. This kind of problem (I'm refering to iii)) happens when the space is not Hausdorff.

Comment: @Tomás: Good point. Without textbook at hand I forget the various separation axioms...